# Flexbox Vertical and horizontal center with bootstrap classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am trying to vertically align my login screen. [Here is my code in JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snnz7c35/) and used the css

```
.flexbox-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;.
    align-items: center;
}
```

I am not getting my items vertically centered. Will i wont be able to achieve it since i use bootstrap class to horizontal center.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4**

Bootstrap 4 is *flexbox* by default, and there are [flexbox utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) for centering and alignment. The `align-items-center` class will work to [vertically center rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388989/bootstrap-4-center-vertical-and-horizontal-alignment/44801382#44801382).

---

**Bootstrap 3.x** (orignal answer)

It will center both horizontally and vertically if you make the div and it's containers 100% height:

```
html,
body,
.fluid-container {
    height: 100%;
}

.flexbox-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://bootply.com/u4Srz4BLgt)

Another option ([for modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)) is to set the full height using `vh` viewport unit:

```
.flexbox-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

[Demo 2](http://bootply.com/spdI2UIYiB)

Comment: I felt the need to do justice and upvote your answer @Skelly. Not only because I hate when they downvote without leaving a comment but also because your code it's correct.